# Import namespace in xml element

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to change the namespace of OrderDetail element in my Main.xsd to be the namespace of an imported element in OrderTypes.xsd. 
In picture q1s i show the correct namespace of OrderType. 
In picture q2s i show the wrong namespace that i want to change to "http://NamespaceTest.com/OrderTypes". Any ideas? Thx in adv.

[image: Correct namespace for OrderType]
[image: Namespace for OrderDetail that i want to change to the one for OrderType]
Main.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ord="http://NamespaceTest.com/OrderTypes"
           targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/Purchase"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/OrderTypes" schemaLocation="OrderTypes.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="Purchase">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="OrderDetail" type="ord:OrderType" /> <!-- Problem: OrderDetail must be in namespace OrderTypes but when i use the main.xsd file OrderDetail is in namespace Purchase -->
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

OrderTypes.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/OrderTypes"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="OrderType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Item"
                  maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ProductName"
                        type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Quantity"
                        type="xs:int" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Why, exactly, do you want to change the namespace of OrderDetail?

Comment: When i deserialize my OrderDetail object i get an exception because my code expects an object in namespace OrderTypes but gets an object in namespace Purchase.

Comment: Are you asking how to fix your _code_ to expect the 'Purchase' namespace? Or are you asking how to fix the XSD?

Comment: I'm asking for a xsd fix, so OrderDetail gets in the OrderTypes namespace

Comment: OK. In that case, please post the actual code of the XSD, and remove the screenshots. Othewise it becomes needlessly difficult to answer your question accurately.